# Same Product Multiple Prices

Tags: magento, opencart, nopcommerce

Please Bear with me as I know It needs research from my side but still want to ask as It would make things a lot easier for me.

Here is what I want to implement.

An online shop where I would configure admin areas for different store owners (vendors). The store owner can belong to same area or different areas. Using the admin area, each store owner can select from pre-configured list of products and define prices for the products in different locations where they have a physical store. The end user can browse the products listing based on his location (area). If multiple vendors belong to same area as customer, the customer will see the product with multiple prices from different vendors. If none of the vendor configured the product of that area, customer will not see the product.

Now the question is, what would be the appropriate option for the above requirements.

Magento, Opencart, nopcommerce or something else?

Comment: None will give you the options you desire out of the box, all of them would require some serious coding. So from my point of view Opencart fits best you description, and its by far the easiest to edit.

Comment: As Jonid suggest none will meet your need - I suggest to go with Magento. There are already some modules available for distributor management.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will try both opencart and magento

Comment: Though only two comments and both recommend different starting point, I'm for OpenCart as well just as mentioned in the first comment - it's easier to learn, edit and develop for it. I have no personal experience with Magento to be honest, but I know for sure from my ex-colleagues and another friend of mine that the learning curve is much higher, the code is completely unreadable and to find a place in code to edit something You'll need to go through 20-30 files at least to find the exact place. From what I remember - Magento comes with more features, but also with 1 GB of source codes...

Comment: nice information.. tnx

Comment: Most of the shopping cart are not multi vendor system , using addons like https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Extensions/Magento-Marketplace-Seller-Price-Comparison.html you can achieve the feature which you are talking about .

Answer (score 0):

This is based on my experience. My advice, if you want sth that goes beyond minor tweaks and a couple of new features, stay away from opencart for the time being.

First of all, you will have to pay (not little...) for extensions and mods of often low quality and crappy support. You should also feel lucky to find one that will cover all the features you want and interoperability between extensions is just non-existent. And if you ask for more features chances are you will have to pay again. There are some free extensions but most are a joke. Like, put a link in your footer or disable sth.

So your next option is coding. Opencart is easy to learn if you know basic php and you can start writing code fast. But.. Opencart lacks a solid mechanism for extending it (until v2.0 at least) and after a while it gets both chaotic and frustrating. Also, you will often need to implement stuff that needs some basic backend functionality from opencart but which is either offered in a way that is useless to you or with basic needed features absent. As a result you will find yourself creating your own "library" of functions that will allow you later to focus on your extension. Moreover there is actually no framework on which you can rely. Sure there are some functions and some methods that you can use, but that's it.

Another thing. The opencart community is not one of the easiest to go along with. I don't mean they are bad or that they will bite you, but people there try to make money and do not find it easy to share things with you, be it advice or code.  Also, they are competitive. And they do not accept criticism, even suggestions, gladly. And there is a scent of eliticism in some threads that can upset your stomach.

This is how I have experienced opencart. I have to admit that I like opencart itself and I find pleasure in coding for it and even now I am debugging some new extension of mine. But often it reminds me that there is so much lacking and I often spend so much time doing trivial stuff that it makes me wonder if it is worth it.

I do not know about magento. It feels similar to opencart to me.

I would suggest drupal to anyone wanting to implement something custom. There is all a framework and ***powerful*** free as in speech extensions and a great truly **foss** community. There are a couple options there for building an eshop but I would go with the [commerce](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/) module. It takes a while to get used to all the concepts but you can achieve what you want with just mere clicks. You won't even have to write code if you don't want to.

Again I repeat, avoid opencart if you need sth too custom (as you do). If not, opencart is one of the fastest to deploy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and such a detailed reply.